# Replacing Strings with a List of Tuples of Strings

Tags: haskell

I want to write a function called `trained` that takes a string replacement function and a list of word pairs (two-tuples of strings).

I have tried using `map` and lambda function but still getting some error. Any help on this problem would be much appreciated!

Function `train` should have this type of signature: `train :: Eq a => (a -> t) -> [(a, t)] -> a -> t`

Here is some error:

> Couldn't match expected type `[Char] -> b'` 
>   with the actual type `[[Char] -> [Char]]`

**Here is my code:**

```
extend repl old new = \str -> if (str == old) then new 
                              else if (str == new) then old 
                              else (repl str)

train fn lst =  map (\(a,b) -> extend fn a b) lst
```

The function **train** should work out like this:

```
In: let improved = train (\s->s) [("kittens","puppies"),
                      ("tea","coffee"),("Java","Haskell")]

In: map improved ["my","favorite","things","are",
                      "kittens","Java","tea","and","rainbows"]

Out: ["my","favorite","things","are","puppies","Haskell","coffee","and","rainbows"]
```

Comment: Could you please include the error message in your question? (Please do not post an image, and rather copy-and-paste the message, and show us the exact code that produces the error.)

Comment: Don't remove your code just because you got an answer.

Comment: Please do not destroy content. It is not allowed by the site's rules. If you persist you will be reported to the site's moderators. Have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to call `map improved`, but the first argument to `map` has to be a function, and `:t improved` shows you that `improved` is actually a list of functions: `improved :: [[Char] -> [Char]]`. The problem is that `train` is returning a list of functions, rather than a single composed function. To fix that, change `map (\(a,b) -> extend fn a b)` to `foldr (\(a,b) f -> extend f a b) fn`.

Also, your code is a bit unidiomatic and complex. Here's how I'd write it:

```
extend :: Eq a => (a, a) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
extend (old, new) repl str
  | str == old = new
  | str == new = old
  | otherwise = repl str

train :: Eq a => (a -> a) -> [(a, a)] -> a -> a
train = foldr extend

improved :: String -> String
improved = train id [("kittens","puppies"),("tea","coffee"),("Java","Haskell")]
```

---

Now that you edited your question to include a required type signature, there's a change you have to make: `extend` must only do its replacement unidirectionally (i.e., it can't test for `str == new` and replace it with `old`). Here's how it would look idiomatically after that:

```
extend :: Eq a => (a, t) -> (a -> t) -> a -> t
extend (old, new) repl str
  | str == old = new
  | otherwise = repl str

train :: Eq a => (a -> t) -> [(a, t)] -> a -> t
train = foldr extend

improved :: String -> String
improved = train id [("kittens","puppies"),("tea","coffee"),("Java","Haskell")]
```

Comment: I'm still a little bit confused with how you write it since the main point is that we only concern about function "train" . And it's type should be like "train :: Eq a => (a -> t) -> [(a, t)] -> a -> t"

Comment: @MathCoolGuy99 Your question as posted only refers to strings. If you need `train` to have a specific type signature, you should edit that into your question.

Comment: @MathCoolGuy99 Further, if `extend` does its replacement bidirectionally, as it does in your question, then its type can't use both `a` and `t` if you want `train` to hardcode its use.

Comment: If `train` takes a string replacement function and a list of 2 - string tuples, then how can I make it similar to `extend` but operates on list of tuples instead?

Comment: @MathCoolGuy99 That's exactly what `foldr` is doing. Does my latest edit make anything clearer?

Comment: So in your code, `train` still takes string replacement function and a list right? And what is `id` when you tried to declare `improve`?

Comment: @MathCoolGuy99 Yes, `train` still takes a string replacement function and a list (as it must, due to its type). And `id` is the same as `(\s->s)`.

Comment: It works now! Thank you so much!! I will mark this answer as checked!